# Setting a default value for an injectable class

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Here is what I want to do:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyInjectableClass {
   constructor(timeout: number = 50) {
   }
}
```

What I want to accomplish is `timeout` being set to 0 when it is injected, but when it is constructed manually, the calling code can set any value it wants.

That doesn't work because the injector cannot inject a "number", and doesn't realize that there's a default it could use.  This also doesn't work:

```
@Injectable()
class MyInjectableClass {
   constructor(@Optional() timeout: number = 50) {
   }
}
```

That doesn't work because reasons.

What does work is

```
export class MyInjectableClassOptions {
   timeout: number,
}

@Injectable()
export class MyInjectableClass {
   constructor(@Optional() options?: MyInjectableClassOptions) {
      const timeout = options? options.timeout : 50;
   }
}
```

But man, is that ugly and elaborate.  Tell me there is another possibility.

Comment: You could make this a class property on `MyInjectableClass { timeout = 0 }` and in the constructor check whether the `timeout` argument is set. `if (timeout) { this.timeout = timeout }`

Comment: @ExplosionPills -- I am going for less ugly not more ugly!  :-P

Comment: Hi, was there a resolution to this @MichaelLorton? Running in to this exact issue now

I get 

`constructor(@Optional() @Inject('env') private env: string) { this.env = this.env ?? 'development'; }` which is really bad

Answer (score 2):

You can use an InjectionToken to inject simple value.

Something like

```
export const MY_OPTION = new InjectionToken<number>('my-option');
```

And then in your module

```
providers: {provide: MY_OPTION, useValue: 50}
```

And finally in your service

```
constructor(@Inject(MY_OPTION) option: number) {}
```

For the default option, you can use the @Optional attribute in combination with @Inject

Comment: Do you have type error there?  Shouldn't it be `number` not `string`.

Comment: @Malvolio yes you are right. I was typing on my phone, so no compilation error ;)